# How do I filter on multiple criteria in group_by?

Tags: r, filtering

I'm not that great at R, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a number of things consecutively.

This is my starting dataset:

```
df <- data.frame (Name  = c("Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Beth", "Beth", "Clark"),
                  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5),
                  Month = c(4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8, 1, 1, 6),
                  Day = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9, 9, 2, 2, 7),
                  Grade = c("Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass"))
```

What I'm trying to do is for every unique `Name` take the first `ID` and then filter the rest of the rows for that combination of `Name` and `ID`.

So, what I would want to get back is this:

```
Name   ID  Month  Day  Grade
Alex   1   4      5    Pass
Alex   1   7      5    Fail
Beth   4   1      2    Fail
Beth   4   1      2    Pass
Clark  5   6      7    Fail
```

[Goal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjrTJ.png)

I tried using group_by, pulling Name and ID, and then filter,; but you can't filter for multiple criteria while using %in%. This was my code:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  group_modify(~ head(.x,1L)) %>%
  pull(Name,ID)

df3 <- df %>%
  filter(Name %in% df2, ID %in% df2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these data are representative of your real data, one approach would be just filter when the `ID` equals the minimum ID, while grouping by `Name`:

```
df %>%
  filter(ID == min(ID), .by = Name)

   Name ID Month Day Grade
1  Alex  1     4   5  Pass
2  Alex  1     7   5  Fail
3  Beth  4     1   2  Pass
4  Beth  4     1   2  Fail
5 Clark  5     6   7  Pass
```

A slightly more flexible approach (ie, if `ID` was not in ascending order, a complicated string, etc) is to create a temporary group ID (`temp`) and select the minimum of these IDs by `Name` using `slice_min`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(temp = cur_group_id(), .by = c(Name, ID)) %>%
  slice_min(temp, by = Name) %>% select(-temp)

   Name ID Month Day Grade
1  Alex  1     4   5  Pass
2  Alex  1     7   5  Fail
3  Beth  4     1   2  Pass
4  Beth  4     1   2  Fail
5 Clark  5     6   7  Pass
```

(Note there may be a typo in your desired data, as there is no `Grade == "Fail"` when `Name == "Clark"` in your example data, so it should return `Pass`)